# SAPUI5 - Unable to intercept click event on element

Tags: sapui5

I'm facing a problem with getting control over 'click' event on `sap.viz.ui5.types.legend.Common` which extends `Element` not `Control`. The task is to manage clicks on the ellipsis ("...") in Legend which set as non-scrollable.The main problem, as far as I understand, is that the Legend is not a control and it's kinda tricky to catch onclick event for it.

Comment: fyi, this is Experimental API and should not be used in a productive system.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean? what exactly is Experimental API?

Comment: Meaning it is not necessarily stable and might change (or be removed) in future versions.

Comment: ok, meaning of 'experimental' is understood. but the ways of getting control over events in Controls are pretty good documented, do you think that it's possible they will be changed (or removed) in future? or this only about Elements, that was my question about?

Comment: No, general Control and Event handling will probably be stable.
I was referring to everything below `sap.viz.`, which should not be used productively.

Comment: uh, ok, i see. but here, unfortunately, i have no choice - the Legend is meant to be used in Controls like Pie-chart or so.